# Convert CSV to AVRO in NiFi 1.13.0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, avro

I would like to convert my CSV dataflow to AVRO in NiFi 1.13.0 and send it to a Kafka topic with a Key and his Schema.

So I have multiple problems:

- Convert my file in AVRO (compatible for Kafka Topic and Kakfa Stream use)
- Send my AVRO message to my Kafka topic with his Schema
- Attach a custom Key with my message

I saw many things about processors that does not exist anymore so I would like to have a clear answer for the 1.13.0 NiFi version.

Here is my dataFlow :

```
Project,Price,Charges,hours spent,Days spent,price/day
API,75000,2500,1500,187.5,1000
```

Here is the AVRO Schema I'd like to have at the end :

```
{
  "name": "projectClass",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Project",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "Price",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "Charges",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "hours spent",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "Days spent",
      "type": "double"
    },
    {
      "name": "price/day",
      "type": "int"
    }
  ]
}
```

The associated key must be a unique ID (int or double).
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: "I saw many things about processors that does not exist anymore..." - can you add specific details about the problem you are facing, like any exception, doubt about processor configuration etc. To start with, use something `GetFile => ConvertRecord => UpdateAttribute/ExecuteScript to generate key =>  PublishKafka`

Comment: Currently, I have the following Dataflow : `GetFile => ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor => SplitRecord => UpdateAttribute => PublishKafkaRecord_2_6`

It seems that I don't really know what to do with my UpdateAttribute and I tried many different things but I never succeed at my task. It could be lovely to see how you are setting up your arguments and your Controller services.

Comment: GetFile -> ConvertExcelToCsv -> PublishKafkaRecord with a CSVReader and an AvroRecordSetWriter. If the key already exists in the data, use the "Message Key Field" and point it at the key field. If it doesn't already exist, stick an UpdateRecord before the PublishKafkaRecord to insert a field to the record with a key.

Comment: Ok for the key, i'm trying to setting up this solution but I'd like to know how to precisely set up the AvroRecordSetWriter, it seems that my Kafka control center do not recognize my Avro Schema. I just have an Avro binary in the message and it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You'll need to configure Nifi's Avro writer with a Confluent Schema Registry if you expect Control Center to work